# Unable to send multipart form data to backend using axios from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to debug this ReactJS code where no matter what I try the backend doesn't receive any data in the body and the file is undefined. I checked by printing all the data(user and element.files[0]) till the line just before the axios request and all seems to be working fine.

Just when the request reaches backend, data doesn't show.

Partial js code:

```js
    async function updateAvatar(element) {
        let data = new FormData();
        // `user` is an object that exists as a state 
        data.append('user', user);
        data.append('file', element.files[0])
        const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/user/upload_avatar`, data, {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
        });
    }
```

Partial HTML code:

```html
<label htmlFor='update-avatar'><span className='btn btn-outline-primary'>Update</span></label>
<input id='update-avatar' type={'file'} className='custom-file-upload' onChange={e => updateAvatar(e.target)} />
```

The code was working till yesterday and is not sending data properly since today.

Does anyone see any issues with the code?

Comment: Try change `type={'file'}` to `type='file'`

Comment: This isn't the problem cus I am already getting the file data into my function

Comment: If you do `console.log(data)` before your axios post request, does it show your data?

Comment: Yes it does show an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really really simple. I had difference in variable name(`user`) in the frontend FormData() and the backend multer code(`user_name`). This was causing the issue. By changing the variable name in multer to user, the request works fine.